# Использование dll из различных процессов

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

Использую в приложении(`windows` сервис) на `C#`, `dll` написаную на `Delphi`. Код `dll` у меня есть. Если я загружаю ее из одной копии, то все отрабатывает нормально. Если я использую несколько копий приложения , то они падают даже не попадая в обработчик `try catch`. падает на `LaodLibrary`. Как безболезненно  использовать одну dll с разными процессами.

Comment: Скорее всего вам не хватает синхронизации при использовании попробуйте `Mutex` он работает на уровне ядра ОС что позволит асинхронно использовать методы и саму либу

Comment: Скорее всего, что-то валится в DllMain. Я бы поискал, где авторы пользуются глобальной памятью или глобальными объектами.